# How to stop NIntegrate if the integral appears to be smaller than certain value?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a number of integral to compute numerically. The values of some of them are small as those take NIntegrate very long to compute according to its internal goals.
Now, I care only about the integrals which absolute value is large, and anything lower than certain threshold (say, 10^-3) is effectively zero. How I can stop NIntegrate as soon as the value of the integral is below the threshold? As I understand AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal are not doing this, as they affect the accuracy of large integrals as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, the functions I'm integrating change sign multiple times

Comment: You can make quick estimates using low values for the options PrecisionGoal, AccuracyGoal, MaxPoints, and MaxRecursion. And/or using `Method->"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"`. From the quick estimates you can decide with which integrands to proceed.